# ScrollView not Showing Keyboard On its container View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I have a Scrolleview and i had its container View a UIView and UIVew contains textfields but Keyboard is not Poping..

I had use this methods...

```
-(void)scrollViewAdaptForEditingtext:(UITextField*)textfield {        
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(0, textfield.frame.origin.y - 1.5 * textfield.frame.size.height);    
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:point animated:YES]; 
}

-(void)scrollViewEndEditingtext:(UITextField*)textfield {    
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(0, 0);    
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:point animated:YES];    
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {    
    [self scrollViewAdaptForEditingtext:textField];    
    return YES;    
}

#pragma TextFieldDelegateProtocol
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {    
    if (textField == self.txtFieldFirstName) {    
        [self.txtFieldLastName becomeFirstResponder];
    } else if (textField == self.txtFieldLastName) {          
        [self.txtFieldEmail becomeFirstResponder];
    } else if (textField == self.txtFieldEmail) {            
        [self.txtFieldMobNumber becomeFirstResponder];
    } else if (textField == self.txtFieldMobNumber) {            
        [self.txtFieldGender becomeFirstResponder];
    } else           
        [textField resignFirstResponder];

    [self scrollViewEndEditingtext:textField];
    return YES;
}
```

can I include uiview also

Comment: If you KNow the Answer plzz tell me

Comment: format your code here first, very hard to see.

Comment: Ok Wait,but did u understand what Problem am I facing..

Comment: Yes, but I will do it in Swift.

Comment: ok no problem Freind

Comment: r u user that line becomeFirstResponder get hit ? Are u testing in simulator ?